# Unit test case with automapper and microsfot fakes framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper, microsoft-fakes

I am writing unit test case using microsoft fakes framework for below api code. I have created shim objects for MyQueryBuilder, GetMyFunctionDetails, Execute functions for the functions from my query builder class. But, I'm getting the following error at line return `result.ToList()`

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The mapper is I guess failing to map the database entity to DTO. I am not sure how this can be handled. Any help would be great.

```
public IList<MyDTO> GetAPI(string ID, bool IsActive)
{
    using (var ctx = new DataContext())
    {
        var mapper = AutomapperBuilder.MyMapperFunction(ctx);
        MyQueryBuilder obj = new MyQueryBuilder(ctx);
        obj.GetMyFunctionDetails(id, true);
        List<DatabaseEntityObject> lst = new List<DatabaseEntityObject>();
        lst = obj.Execute().AsQueryable().ToList();
        var result = mapper.ProjectTo<MyDTO>(lst.AsQueryable());
        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

Below is the unit test case

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_ResultOk()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        //Arrange                
        List<DatabaseEntityObject> lstTaskDetailsDTO = null;
        using (var ctx = new DataContext())
        {
            MyQueryBuilder objQueryBuilder = new MyQueryBuilder(ctx);
            ShimMyQueryBuilder.AllInstances.GetMyFunctionDetailsStringBoolean = (_, __, ___) =>
            {
                return objQueryBuilder;
            };
            ShimMyQueryBuilder.AllInstances.Execute = (_) =>
            {
                lstTaskDetailsDTO = new List<DatabaseEntityObject>()
                {
                    new DatabaseEntityObject
                    {
                        projectid = PID
                        name = Name
                    }
                };
                return lstTaskDetailsDTO;
            };
            //Act
            var controller = new MyController();
            var result = controller.GetMyAPI(ID, true);
            //Assert
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Provided API and Unit test case code.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Moq`?

Comment: As per requirement I have to use just Microsoft fakes framework.